# Unable to load Mnist Data from git clone

Tags: python, import, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, mnist

I'm following along with Michael Nielsens book on Neural Networks. I am trying to run the code

```
>>> import mnist_loader
```

in my python 2.7 terminal, however i am getting the error:

```
ImportError: No module named mnist_loader
```

I've cloned the https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning repository, which is located at C:\Users\einsn\Documents\GitHub\neural-networks-and-deep-learning. How do I import the mnist_loader from this repository?

The described book can  be found here:
http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html

Comment: Any reason you want to use Python 2 instead of Python 3? Python 3 came out in 2008, and Python 2 is outdated and unsupported?